# Ubuntu 22.04: infinite authorization loop, cannot connect to wifi

Tags: networking, 22.04

For some reason I have mysteriously started getting repeated "Authorization required" popups when I try to connect to any network. Even if I type the correct password, the popup keeps showing up. So I cannot connect to any network.

I was using my laptop just fine earlier this morning. No updates past couple of days. Later this afternoon, I first got that message after rebooting and had to struggle to just log in. But after logging in, I am facing the problem described above. I am new to Linux, so please let me know what information you would need to help me. Thanks!

Comment: `But after logging in, I am facing the problem described above`, how can you get `Authorization required`  after you have "logged in"? Please explain.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to say I get the popup when I try to connect to a public Wi-Fi network that I have auto connected to several times in the past. Am heading back home now and fear the same problem will persist when I try to connect through my router.

Comment: My home network connection through the router autoconnected without any issues. For now. So it seems like any public Wi-Fi is going to give me this problem. Any ideas on why I might be getting those infinite loops?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot the "Authorization required" pop-up issue by following these steps.

1. Enable Network Manager to autostart with `sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager`
2. Restart Network Manager with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`
3. Forget and reconnect to the network.

   - Click the Wi-Fi icon on the right side of the top panel.
   - Select *Forget* for the problematic network.
   - Reconnect to the network by entering the correct password.
4. Check Network Manager logs with `sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager | less`
5. If you're using a VPN or proxy, temporarily disable them to check if they're interfering.
6. Update Network Manager and other packages with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`